# What is the Linux system call for modifying file flags?

Tags: linux

I'm looking to write a kernel module that can intercept and block operations that seek to change the bits for the immutable and append-only flags on files. It's supposedly `fcntl()`, but I didn't see parameters for file/folder name or the new flag bits. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fchmodat+2

Comment: This question belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KevinDTimm No, it doesn't. This is a programming question, it's on-topic here and it's off-topic on [unix.se] which is only for user and administrator questions.

Comment: You can't call a system call from inside the kernel. By definition, a system call is made from userland to the kernel. Are you writing a kernel module or userland code? What information do you want to find the flags from?

Comment: It's a kernel module for intercepting a particular system call. I'm not sure I understand your last question.

Answer (score 0):

fcntl() is for changing attributes of open file descriptors. You are probably looking for the chmod (or fchmod or fchmodat) syscalls as defined in [fs/open.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/open.c?id=refs/tags/v3.18-rc7#n513).

Comment: Nope. I'm looking for a system call.

Comment: That *is* a syscall. Added link to implementation inside the Linux kernel.

Comment: The system call that I wanted was `ioctl`, not `fcntl`. "File attributes" refers to the attributes of a file that are modified with `chattr`, NOT the flags that are selected by a process that opens a file.

Answer (score 0):

> block operations that seek to change the bits for the
>   immutable and append-only flags on files

Since the *append-only flag* can only be the file status flag **O_APPEND**, the system call that is to be intercepted therefor is, as you supposed, [`fcntl()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/fcntl.c#n359) - see the [fcntl(2) Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html):

```
File status flags
   Each open file description has certain associated status flags,
   initialized by open(2) and possibly modified by fcntl().  Duplicated
   file descriptors (made with dup(2), fcntl(F_DUPFD), fork(2), etc.)
   refer to the same open file description, and thus share the same file
   status flags.

   The file status flags and their semantics are described in open(2).

   F_GETFL (void)
          Return (as the function result) the file access mode and the
          file status flags; arg is ignored.

   F_SETFL (int)
          Set the file status flags to the value specified by arg.  File
          access mode (O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR) and file creation
          flags (i.e., O_CREAT, O_EXCL, O_NOCTTY, O_TRUNC) in arg are
          ignored.  On Linux, this command can change only the O_APPEND,
          O_ASYNC, O_DIRECT, O_NOATIME, and O_NONBLOCK flags.  It is not
          possible to change the O_DSYNC and O_SYNC flags; see BUGS,
          below.
```

However, note that *access mode **O_RDONLY*** cannot be changed with `fcntl()`.